# Multi-line menu item descriptions in curses

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, curses

I've got a menu in curses that I'd like to put multi-line descriptions onto.

My code puts the description fields on but they don't display if they don't fit on the line.

Curses is happy enough printing multi-line text as strings (not as menu descriptions)

Any ideas how to get multi-line descriptions working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up on this and render my own scrollable list of items instead.

Comment: Did you by chance create a new library for this?

Comment: The code not my IP due to the contract it was developed under. The menu system code is just part of the application, and is coupled to the async part of the system so that events can make the menu system change state. And not designed to be generic; it's got 40 column limits hard-coded into it, for example.